# How to display a list of images in ASP.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to display a list of images

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{         
   return View(db.User.ToList());
}
```

In the View

```
@model IEnumerable<User.Models.User>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
         <img src=@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Image) alt="Profile Image" width="20" height="20"/>
}
```

The code above shows a broken link for image.
The html code is

```
<img src="~/Images/" alt="Profile Image" width="20" height="20">
```

My question how can I display the photos as list?
Such as

Person1       ImageofPerson1
Person2       ImageofPerson2
Person3       ImageofPerson3

Comment: what is item.Image returning, is it a base64 string ?

Comment: How I can know that

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky to guess what "broken link for image" means, it would be helpful if you posted the generated HTML. In any case, two suggestions that might already help:

1. Remove the `DisplayFor()` and just place the raw value in there.
2. Place quotes ("") around the `src` value in case your URL's contain spaces.

   ```
   @foreach (var item in Model) {
       <img src="@item.Image" alt="Profile Image" width="20" height="20">
   }
   ```

I also changed the `/>` at the end to `>`. This doesn't fix anything in your situation, but that's proper HTML. `/>` is something we used to do in XHTML.

If this doesn't fix it, please post the generated HTML to debug further.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working the html code is <img alt="Profile Image" width="20" height="20">

Comment: Ah, well that explains something. `@item.Image` simply does not contain a URL to photo. Either find a property on `@item` that does or fill `@item.Image` with a URL value.